# A consequence of Cesàro's theorem

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, proof-writing

Here is the statement :

"Let $(a_n)_{n\ge 1}$ a real or complex sequence and $l \in \bar{\mathbb{R}}$.

If $\lim \limits_{n\to +\infty} a_{n+1} - a_{n}=l$, then $\lim \limits_{n\to +\infty}\frac{a_n}{n}=l$."

To prove this, I take the sequence $u_n = a_{n+1} - a_{n}$ for all $n\ge1$.

By hypothesis, $\lim \limits_{n\to +\infty} u_n = l$. Then by applying Cesàro's theorem I must have $\lim \limits_{n\to +\infty}\frac{1}{n} \sum \limits_{k=1}^{n}u_k=l$

By replacing I get : $\lim \limits_{n\to +\infty}\frac{a_{n+1}-a_1}{n}=l$ $\Leftrightarrow$ $\lim \limits_{n\to +\infty}\frac{a_{n+1}}{n}=l$

Then I don't know how to make appear $a_n$ instead of $a_{n+1}$.

Moreover, does the sequence $a_n$ require condition to apply this result ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: $$\frac{a_{n+1}}{n}=\frac{a_{n+1}}{n+1}\frac{n+1}{n}.$$

---

Or perhaps more to the point, $$\frac{a_{n+1}}{n+1}=\frac{a_{n+1}}{n}\frac{n}{n+1}.$$We've shown $a_{n+1}/n\to l$, we know $n/(n+1)\to1$, hence $a_{n+1}/(n+1)\to l$.

And now this implies that $a_n/n\to l$. Given $\epsilon>0$ there exists $N$ so $|a_{n+1}/(n+1)-l|<\epsilon$ for all $n>N$. Hence $|a_n/n-l|<\epsilon$ for all $n>N+1$.

Comment: But you still have $a_{n+1}$ not $a_n$

Comment: Ok, this gives me a better idea where the problem lies. It's very easy to show that if $\lim x_{n+1}=L$ then $\lim x_n=L$. (Let $\epsilon>0$. Choose $N$ so $|x_{n+1}-L|<\epsilon$ for all $n>N$. Then $|x_n-L|<\epsilon$ for all $n>N+1$.)

Comment: It's better, so for $n\to +\infty$ , $\lim \limits_{n\to +\infty}\frac{a_{n+1}}{n}= \lim \limits_{n\to +\infty}\frac{a_{n}}{n}=l$. That's it ?

Comment: Yes or no, depending on exactly what argument you have in mind. I added some more detail to my answer that may help. (Gotta go...)

Comment: I mean that in your proof you just change the rank $N$ to $N+1$ to check the ineguality with $a_n$. I just wanted to say that $+\infty$ is big enough to write $\lim \limits_{n\to +\infty} \frac{a_{n+1}}{n}=\frac{a_{n+1}}{n+1}\frac{n+1}{n}=\lim \limits_{n\to +\infty} \frac{a_{n}}{n}$.

Comment: Well I guess I'd say yes to that...

Comment: I was also thinking about an argument of extracting sequence. Will it work in that case ?

Comment: ??? Why? We have a simple proof already. (And no, it seems to me you exxtract a subsequence you're going to prove something about a subsequence, which is not what you want to prove.)

Comment: I was wondering if $x_n$ was an extraction from $x_{n+1}$ even if it sounds weird..

Comment: Oh, that's what you were getting at! That's not quite right, because $(x_n)=(x_1,...)$ and there's no $x_1$ in $(x_{n+1})$. But $x_n$ is _almost_ a subsequence of $x_{n+1}$, and yes that's the whole point.

Comment: Indeed, thanks the initial proof is clearer